# Get method on Rest API e.x search by name or genre?(Spring)

Tags: java, sql, spring, rest, get

I am trying to build up a REST API for an Artist Project.
So the Project has two tables:

Artist -id,name,genre

Genre-id,name.

Artists class has this object:

```
  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "fk_genre_id")
  private Genres genres;
```

The problem is i have to do a get method that searches Artist by name or genre.
This is what i've tried to do :

@Repository
public interface ArtistRepository extends JpaRepository{

```
@Query( "Select a FROM Artists a INNER JOIN Genres g on a.genres.getid()=g.getid() where a.name = searchkey or g.name=searchkey")
Artists getArtistbynameorgenre(@Param("name") String searchkey);
```

}

I don't have perfect knowledge of SQL syntax and i think the problem is at the query syntax.

Answer (score 0):

As you guess the problem is with your `SQL` query.
change your query to:

```
@Query( "Select a FROM Artists a INNER JOIN a.genres g on a.genre = g.genre-id where a.name = ?1 or g.name=?1")
Artists getArtistbynameorgenre(String searchkey);
```

I hope it works :)

Comment: Hi! I tried it,a new error happens...Path expected for join!.Any knowledge on this ?

Comment: @JetaKasabaqi check the new query, I had forgotten to address `genres` as `a.genres`. also you can use the way @EkanshRastogi mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can simply use spring data to get the data as follows

```
@Repository public interface ArtistRepository extends JpaRepository{

    List<Artist> artists = findAllByIdOrGenre_Name(String searchkey, String searchkey);

}
```